# Follow path given by Google Directions API at an average speed (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directory-api

I'm programming and app to allow parents remotely access their children position throughout a previously specified route.
To choose the origin and destination I use google maps API and then ask the Google directions API for the best route between those points and draw a polyline between those points.

[My application - markers in initial position and destination, polyline drawn using route retrieved from Direction API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnI81.png)

I could periodically send the child's position to the parent's device (latitude and longitude) and draw the polyline between those points but that's not my goal. My goal is to have the child's device send initial position and average speed for the first few meters of the path to the parent's device(no problem), and have the parent's device simulate the trajectory by following the previously drawn route ,received from directions api, at an average speed(problem).

Is this possible to draw a simulation following the previously drawn route? I already took a look at the google "snap to roads" but it's not exactly what I'm looking for...
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497130/how-can-i-extrapolate-farther-along-a-road/38616162#38616162 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758825/dynamic-polyline-colors-with-google-maps-android-app/35789936#35789936

Comment: Thanks @antonio ! The first link you provided is very useful.