# How to plot the marker in the middle point of the polyline in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I plotted a polyline in a Google Map and I want a marker in the polyline when the polyline is clicked. Then only the marker should appear in the middle of the polyline.

```
@Override
public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
    double latitude = polyline.getPoints().get(0).latitude;
    double longitude = polyline.getPoints().get(0).longitude;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .zoom(18).build();
}
```

With the code above the marker gets plotted only at the first point, but I need it in the middle of the polyline. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the center of a polyline by getting the bound's center.

I haven't executed the code but I hope it will work fine.

```
public LatLng getPolylineCentroid(Polyline p) {

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < p.getPoints().size(); i++){
        builder.include(p.getPoints().get(i));
    }

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    return bounds.getCenter();
}
```

Comment: This method assumes the earth is flat. it's not geodesic.

Comment: this work if polyline is straight line, 
we should use **extrapolate** method to get latlan that is as distance sent

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extrapolate` function that I propose in this solution: [How can I extrapolate farther along a road?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497130/how-can-i-extrapolate-farther-along-a-road/38616162#38616162)

```
double middleDistance = SphericalUtil.computeLength(polyline.getPoints());

LatLng markerPosition = extrapolate(polyline.getPoints(), polyline.getPoints().get(0), middleDistance);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(markerPosition)
    .zoom(18).build();
```

Comment: When I try this, the extrapolate method returns null with !PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath, which doesn't make sense to me, considering the inputs.